# Does there always exist a Brute-Force approach?

Tags: algorithm, brute-force

I have gone through a lot of algorithms. I solved a lot of programming questions & found various approaches to solve a single problem probably from brute-force to the best one.

I was wondering if there is any problem that cannot be solved using a brute-force approach but can be solved by any better approach?

Comment: How about [this problem](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=67)? *If you could check one trillion (10^12) routes every second it would take over twenty billion years to check them all.*

Comment: Hmm I don't really understand the question, perhaps that's just me but could you edit your post to clarify?

Comment: @assylias: that's a matter of scale.  If you scale down any problem far enough, I believe there's always a brute-force solution, but I'm not positive.

Comment: I don't think you are right - look at the halting problem, I wrote down

Answer (score 12):

There exists a brute-force algorithm if a solution is known to exist (such as if it's an optimization problem for instance) and if the set of candidate solutions is [enumerable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration) (and if, for each candidate solution, you  can decide if it is correct or not).

Problems that are [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) for instance, don't have a brute force solution of course.

Comment: realistically may or may not factor into it - that's just a matter of if the brute force solution will complete before <some catastrophic event like you dying or the universe exploding>

Comment: Undecidable problems cannot be solved by *any* approach, brute-force or not. Also, even if a problem is enumerable, it doesn't guarantee a brute-force solution (e.g. when it requires enumerating everything).

Comment: Is there a proof that brute-force algorithm will exist for enumerable but infinite solution set?

Comment: @AndreyErmakov, Isn't it evident that `for each solution s, if checkSolution(s) then print s and exit` will do? If there exists a solution, it will terminate within finite time.

Comment: @aioobe: no, it will terminate, but not necessarily within a finite time.

Comment: @aioobe e.g. for iterative process there may be a infinite but enumerable sequence of solutions. Each of them approximates the exact one but not equal to it.

Comment: @MooingDuck, which of the enumerable solutions would trigger an infinite execution? (I know I'm on deep water here ;)

Comment: @AndreyErmakov, are you talking about the case where the solution is a real number for instance? (The set of real numbers is not enumerable I believe.)

Comment: @aioobe You are almost right - if there is solution you will terminate eventually. But if there is no solution, and the set of possible solution is infinite, you won't terminate.

Comment: @aioobe You're right, but the set of solutions provided by such algorithm will be a enumerable (countable) subset of it. Although I agree with your answer as in that particular case it's possible to define "correctness" to stop eventually.

Comment: @barak, okey.. answer updated :-)

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you mean by *can*.

For almost any problem with a finite number of possible solutions, there is a brute force solution. Given enough computing power and/or time, it can be solved using that solution.

For some problems, it's not *practially* possible to use a brute force solution, because you don't possess enough computing power and/or time.

In the specific case of the [Euler Project](http://projecteuler.net/), many problems are designed so that the brute force solution requires too much computing power and/or time. A problem could for example be designed to take a million years to compute given the currently available computers, forcing you to use another approach in order to complete it soon enough that the solution is useful.

Comment: Is there any problem with a finite number of solutions that can't be solved using brute force? (Besides, there exists problems with an infinite number of solutions that can be solved using brute-force.)

Comment: @aioobe: I don't have a specific example, but I dare not say that there isn't one. A problem could for example be constructed so that any valid solution would be invalid just because it is found, or a problem could have a solution that could only be proven, but not tested.

Comment: Look at the halting problem, you can't fund brute-force algorithm to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if there is any problem that cannot be solved using a brute-force approach but can be solved by any better approach?

Yes. Sometimes proving decidability is nontrivial.

1) Planarity:

How to test if a graph is planar? Naively, you cannot use brute force because there are infinitely many ways you can draw the graph.

Once you find out that there [exist clever criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Kuratowski.27s_and_Wagner.27s_theorems) for planarity, an algorithm is straightforward.

2) Presburger formulas:

A formula in Presburger arithmetic is built using quantifiers ∀, ∃, addition +, constants (natural numbers) and logical operators. Anything different is not allowed. Quantifiers range over natural numbers.

Examples:

∀n ∃m (n = m + m) or (n = m + m + 1)

This formula expresses the fact that every integer is even or odd. It's true.

∃m ∀n ∃k m + k = n

This formula expresses the fact that there exists a largest natural number. It's false.

Is there an algorithm that will decide whether a formula is true or not? Naively, brute force will not work because you need to check all natural numbers. [The problem is decidable](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/03/07/finite-state-automata-binary-decision-diagrams-and-presburger-arithmetic/), though.

Comment: Are you claiming that there exists an algorithm that decides whether or not a presburger formula is valid or not, but there's no brute-force approach to solving it?

Comment: @aioobe: Yes. By "brute force" I mean you cannot directly compute values of the quantifiers, as they range over natural numbers; the problem is trivially decidable if quantifiers ranged over finite sets.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The very concept of brute-force means try everything.  So if something can be created and recreated to match, then trying every possible permutation will result in finding another match.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously yes, as long as we're solving a problem which is defined on some discrete space and non-empty solution set exists.

Consider the following:

1. First algorithm to solve a new problem is a naïve brute-force approach.
2. If one has been found, why would anybody look for another? Because in discrete problems brute-force means enumerating on sets of input values until the solution will be found and has O(n!) or O(a<sup>n</sup>) computational [complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Evaluating_run-time_complexity).
3. The latter means it not useable in practice and the more tricky approach needed. Alternatively we may look for approximate solution instead of exact, but that will introduce conditions for convergence.
4. Finally there's a [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problem class.

Comment: 4. is very deeply mistaken: NP-complete problems must have verifiable solutions, and they must be NP-hard; it is open whether there are polynomial algorithms for NP-complete problems; even if P=NP, not every problem outside P is in NP.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems that can't be solved with brute-force.

For example, look at the [halting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) problem :
You need to design an algorithm that receives a program and an input, and return "True" if the the program will eventually halt when run with that input, and "False" if not.

The algorithm must stop eventually and tell "False" or "True".

Needless to say, but there is no such algorithm.

**EDIT:**

When you say "solve" I assume you mean to computationally solve.

I think yes - look at the following problem:

You are given the loop:

while (x < m)

```
x--
```

And the constants m and k.
And you need to return the minimum x that < k that the loop will terminate if exist, and "False" otherwise.
Using brute-force algorithm, for k = 999 and m = 1000 you will start with x = 999 (because the demand that x < k = 999) and you will get stuck forever.

You can use better approach - if m < k, return m. Otherwise, return "False".

Comment: Halting problem is a bad example, since OP asked for a "problem that cannot be solved using a brute-force approach _but can be solved by any better approach_".

Comment: You are right, I didn't see the rest of the sentence.